# Generalized cartesian product function in Scala

Tags: scala

I wrote the following cartesian product function (which can take an *arbitrary* number of `Iterable`s on elements of various types):

```
def cross(a: Iterable[_]*): Iterable[_] =
   if (a.length == 1)
     for (i <- a.head) yield i
   else
     for (i <- a.head; j <- cross3(a.tail:_*))
       yield i :: j :: Nil
```

Which produces, e.g.:

```
List(List(1, List(a, -1)), List(1, List(a, 0)) ...
```

But I wanted something like:

```
List(List(1, a, -1), List(1, a, 0) ...
```

Or even better:

```
List((1, a, -1), (1, a, 0) ...
```

How would I "flatten" the resulting tuples? I tried a few things, but the type inference seems to get lost inferring that the type of j is `Any`.

Comment: Are all the `Iterable`s passed to the function the same length? What happens if they're not? Is the length of the result the length of the shortest in the input? Also, values of type `List(List(1, a, 1), ...` are problematic, because interior lists have heterogeneous elements. The _[Shapeless](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless)_ library may be of use to you here...

Comment: For a cartesian product, I would think that the various `Iterable`s can have any length. The length of the result for `1,2,3` and `a,b` is actually 6.

Comment: Doh! Of course! :-)

Comment: But how would you represent an empty list in the output? It doesn't appear to produce values that would be recorded in each tuple result, but that would mean that the number of values in each tuple could be less than the number of iterables in the input list. Is that OK?

Comment: Hmm - good point. Let's assume none of the iterables is empty?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want something like this (using *Shapeless*):

```scala
import shapeless._

object CartesianProduct
extends App {

  def cross(a: Iterable[Iterable[_]]): Iterable[HList] = {

    // If a is empty, return HNil to signal the end of this heterogenous list.
    if(a.isEmpty) Iterable(HNil)

    // Otherwise, create a new heterogeneous list for each element in this list,
    // prefixed to each heterogeneous list for the remainder.
    else for {

      i <- a.head // For each element in the head sequence
      t <- cross(a.tail) // For each heterogenous list in the output sequence
    } yield i :: t // Create a new heterogeneous list
  }

  val data = List(List(1, 2, 3), List("a", "b"), List(-1, -2, -3))
  val result = cross(data)
  println(result)
}
```

Result is:

```scala
List(1 :: a :: -1 :: HNil, 1 :: a :: -2 :: HNil, 1 :: a :: -3 :: HNil, 1 :: b :: -1 :: HNil, 1 :: b :: -2 :: HNil, 1 :: b :: -3 :: HNil, 2 :: a :: -1 :: HNil, 2 :: a :: -2 :: HNil, 2 :: a :: -3 :: HNil, 2 :: b :: -1 :: HNil, 2 :: b :: -2 :: HNil, 2 :: b :: -3 :: HNil, 3 :: a :: -1 :: HNil, 3 :: a :: -2 :: HNil, 3 :: a :: -3 :: HNil, 3 :: b :: -1 :: HNil, 3 :: b :: -2 :: HNil, 3 :: b :: -3 :: HNil)
```

**Update**: Can you do this without using using *Shapeless*?

How about this:

```scala
object CartesianProduct
extends App {

  def cross(a: Iterable[Iterable[_]]): Iterable[List[_]] = {

    // If a is empty, return Nil to signal the end of this list of Anys.
    if(a.isEmpty) Iterable(Nil)

    // Otherwise, create a new list of Anys for each element in this iterable,
    // prefixed to each list of Anys for the remainder.
    else for {

      i <- a.head // For each element in the head sequence
      t <- cross(a.tail) // For each list of Anys in the output sequence
    } yield i :: t // Create a new list of Anys
  }

  val data = List(List(1, 2, 3), List("a", "b"), List(-1, -2, -3))
  val result = cross(data)
  println(result)
}
```

It outputs, in effect, a `List[List[Any]]`:

```scala
List(List(1, a, -1), List(1, a, -2), List(1, a, -3), List(1, b, -1), List(1, b, -2), List(1, b, -3), List(2, a, -1), List(2, a, -2), List(2, a, -3), List(2, b, -1), List(2, b, -2), List(2, b, -3), List(3, a, -1), List(3, a, -2), List(3, a, -3), List(3, b, -1), List(3, b, -2), List(3, b, -3))
```

(The reason type inference gets lost is because, firstly, you do not have any generic types in your function signature, so a generic type of `_` is equivalent to saying your iterables contain `Any` values. Secondly, you're then adding these `Any` values to a `List`. So the list contains heterogeneous elements (`Int` and `String` in this case). Doing anything with the result implies that you're going to have to cast the types, or pattern match on them. To determine if there's a better approach, I have to ask what you're using this function for?)

Returning a list of tuples is, I think, impossible in the general case (since you'd need to determine how many iterables you had in the input to create a tuple with that many values).

**Update 2**: If you want output in the form of tuples, you clearly need to know the number and types of each iterable passed to the function. The *Shapeless* version looks like this:

```scala
// Convert result to a tuple.
val generic = Generic[Tuple3[Int, String, Int]]
val tupleResult = result.map {l =>
  val t = l.asInstanceOf[Int :: String :: Int :: HNil]
  generic.from(t)
}
println(tupleResult)
```

and the non-*Shapeless* version looks like this:

```scala
val tupleResult = result.map {l =>
  (
    l.head.asInstanceOf[Int],
    l.tail.head.asInstanceOf[String],
    l.tail.tail.head.asInstanceOf[Int]
  )
}
println(tupleResult)
```

In both cases, the output will be:

```scala
List((1,a,-1), (1,a,-2), (1,a,-3), (1,b,-1), (1,b,-2), (1,b,-3), (2,a,-1), (2,a,-2), (2,a,-3), (2,b,-1), (2,b,-2), (2,b,-3), (3,a,-1), (3,a,-2), (3,a,-3), (3,b,-1), (3,b,-2), (3,b,-3))
```

Comment: How about not using _Shapeless_? Is Scala on its own unable to do this? What is the blocker? But oh so close! That's what I want yes, just without _Shapeless_ :-)

Comment: @Frank I updated my answer to illustrate how this can be done.

Comment: @Frank I added some further clarification. Does this answer your question?

Comment: Mike - this is a real great answer. Thanks for taking the time to put it together. One suggestion though, could you rename the function from `cross3` to `cross`? I did that also in my OP. The reason I had it as `cross3` was because it was my third attempt, but leaving it as `cross3` could give the impression we expect only 3 parameters ... Thanks!

Comment: Mike - I don't need that function for anything, I was just writing it out to learn Scala and as a personal challenge.